# Как перенести контрол с mainwindow в canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-canvas

Как перенести button из mainwindow в canvas? Вся сложность в том заключается, что перенестись оно должно так, чтобы в canvas оно было на том же месте, как и в mainwindow.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Дополнение к картинке : сама кнопка сначала должна быть как дочерняя у mainwindow, а при нажатии на неё она должна стать дочерней у canvas, но иметь тоже расположение как и в mainwindow.

**UPD** :

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="5997" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="6000"/>
        <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="104,176,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="143" Height="63"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**UPD** :

Если делать как вы сказали то будет :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А мне надо :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPD** :
До нажатия :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если бы была разметка окна, я бы смог вам помочь.

Comment: @ArthurEdgarov а что такое разметка окна? Просто если так будет проще то я лучше переделаю

Comment: подразумевается xaml код)

Comment: @ArthurEdgarov  вот, тему обновил

Answer (score 2):

Grid и Canvas оба наследуются от [Panel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.controls.panel(v=vs.110).aspx), значит у них обеих есть свойство [Children](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.controls.panel.children(v=vs.110).aspx). У свойства [Children](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.controls.panel.children(v=vs.110).aspx) есть методы [`Children.Add()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms603589(v=vs.110).aspx) и [`Children.Remove()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms590022(v=vs.110).aspx). Так и передавайте родительство от грида к канвасу.

Пример:

```
Так можно получить позицию кнопки, и затем использовать её.
Point position = имя кнопки.TranslatePoint(new Point(0,0), (VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(имя_кнопки) as UIElement));
имя_грида.Children.Remove(имя_кнопки);
имя_канваса.Children.Add(имя_кнопки);
```

Comment: Да это понятно, я знаю как его перекидывать с грида в канвас, но если так делать то в результате будет как на картинке которую я обновил в теме.

Comment: @alex-rudenkiy, Обновил ответ, но точно не уверен в работоспособности.

Comment: к сожалению не то, тему обновил :(

Comment: а можно получить каким нибудь образом координаты button на grid относительно canvas?